# how to do a ternary operation in .csh script

Tags: csh

I want to do

```
a = $b == howru ? good : not_good;
```

in c shell script

I tried using `&&` and `||` operators but it seems like I am making some mistake, because I am used to work on Bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, your syntax is wrong:

1. You need to assign variables with `set`
2. `?` .. `:` is not an operator in csh.

The "normal" `csh` `if` statement looks like:

```
if ( cond ) then
  foo
else
  bar
endif
```

You can actually shorten the `if` to

```
if ( cond ) foo
```

But you can't add an `else` here, as far as I know.

A "short" syntax works exactly the same as in bourne shells, except that you need to use the `set` keyword:

```
% [ "howru" = 'howru' ] && set a = good || set a = not_good
% echo $a
good

% [ "XXhowru" = 'howru' ] && set a = good || set a = not_good
% echo $a
not_good
```